# regular language (or not)

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions, finite-automata

I have the language $L = \{ abc^nbc^mba\ |\ m,n \in N, n \geq m  \}$
Could this ever be regular? How can we keep track of $n$ and $m$? I have no way to use memory in my Finite Automata so this cannot possibly be regular? Or am I way off here? No matter how I construct at FA I cannot come over the fact that at any time I wish to loop for $c$ I cannot decide how many times I should be able to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Your intuition is correct: $L$ is not regular. This is easily proved using the [pumping lemma for regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

Suppose that $L$ is regular, and let $p$ be the pumping length. Let $w=abc^pbc^pba$. Then we can write $w=xyz$ in such a way that $|xy|\le p$, $|y|\ge 1$, and $xy^kz\in L$ for each $k\ge 0$. In particular, taking $k=0$ we see that $xz\in L$.

- Show that no matter how $x$ and $y$ are chosen so that $|xy|\le p$, $|y|\ge 1$, and $xy$ is an initial segment of $w$, the word $xz$ is *not* in $L$.

This contradiction shows that $L$ is not regular after all.

Comment: Thank you, so in short, as soon as I have to "keep track" or "count" my steps within my FA it cannot be regular?

Comment: @darrrrUC: You’re welcome. That’s a very good rule of thumb, but it should always be backed up by an actual proof of some kind. Once in a while you run into a situation in which it seems at first glance that you have to keep track of something, but on closer examination there turns out to be a way around this obstacle.

Comment: Yes, Just wanted a rule of thumb before "wasting" time and energy on pumping :) Once more you have saved me from the depths Brian. Thank you!

Comment: @darrrrUC: You’re very welcome!

Comment: @Bran M. Scott I have come to the same conclusion as far as to let $w = abc^pbcP^ba$ But I do not know how I am to split up the string on the form of $xyz$, What I tried to do is $x = ab$, $y=c^{p-2}$ so that $|xy| \leq p$ but this would give me $z = c^2bc^pba$ and this leads to very confusing results. Any hints on how to split up my string on the $xyz$ format? Cheers once again!

Comment: @darrrrUC: You have to show that *every* possible split that satisfies the conditions $|xy|\le p$ and $|y|\ge 1$ gives rise to a contradiction. For instance, if $x$ is empty, then $y$ must include the first $a$. Then $xz$ will be just $z$ and will not start with $a$ (since $y$ is at most $abc^{p-2}$), so it will not be in $L$. A similar problem arises if $x=a$. If $x$ includes the initial $ab$, then $y$ is a string of $c$s, at least one and at most $p-2$. Will the string $xz$ have the right form to belong to $L$?

Comment: Ok, so if $x$ is empty we get (assuming $k =0$) something that does not start with $a$ so this is $\notin L$. if $x = a$ we will miss the first $b$ hence $\notin L$. but if $x = ab$ we would get $abc^2bc^pba \notin L$ Is this correct?

Comment: Or am I confusing things further with $c^2$ part? Since $y = c^{p-2}$ the remaining two $c$'s must be within $z$?

Comment: @darrrrUC: You’re going a bit astray. If $x$ includes the initial $ab$, then there are $r\ge 0$ and $s\ge 1$ such that $x=abc^r$, $y=c^s$, and $r+s\le p-2$ (since $|xy|\le p$). Then $z=c^{p-r-s}bc^pba$, so $xz=abc^{p-s}bc^pba$. But $s>1$, so $p-s<p$, and therefore $xz\notin L$.

Comment: ahhhh yes! Brilliant! Thank you once more!

Comment: @darrrrUC: You’re welcome!